# Space between divs and disable hover animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to code my own circle menu with Yii, like Google Inbox.

It's almost done but I need delete space between **.circle_sub** created because of **.circle_title**.

---

```
 <div id="circle_area">
     <div class="circle_main">MAIN</div>
     <div class="circle_sub"> SUB</div>
     <div class="circle_title">HINT</div>
     <div class="circle_sub"> SUB</div>
     <div class="circle_title">HINT</div>
</div>
```

All code with css [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gcc753zf/).

Comment: use position: absolute; in the place of  position: relative; in .circle_title

Comment: I can't, because then all .circle_title will be displayed in one place. I need every one .circle displayed next to his DOM "precursor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a container for each element of submenu and set `position: relative;` to it and `position: absolute;` to `.circle_title`.

Example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2gknokL/

I also updated JS accordingly...

Comment: I changed **.title_circle** css **left** on **right** because i need constant distance between title and sub. It seems to deal but need one-line hint even for long string. Check please [code](http://jsfiddle.net/n2gknokL/1/)

Comment: To fix this just add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.circle_title`. That should help :)

Comment: Somebody knows why MAIN HINT (next to MAIN) sometimes disapears with delay? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/684jqk5n/)